# Please Undelete my Question

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I would have asked this in the chat room, but it appears to be dead.

I recently asked a question on the main site, which I deleted to migrate over to SuperUser.SE as I was told it was more suitable [there](https://superuser.com/questions/1170676/dropbox-slow-syncing-of-many-small-files). Now I think I see why I was told to post the question there, but my question is about the web service specifically, not a general question about the transferring of files on a computer.

I'd like to migrate my question back and edit to clarify, since I think it belongs here. Can someone please undelete my original question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question isn't about the web portion of Dropbox at all. It's about the file sync service. Only questions about the web interface of Dropbox are on-topic here.

That Super User's community thinks that "how Dropbox does what it does" is off-topic for Super User **does not** indicate that it's then on topic for Web Apps.

So, you should bring up on the [Super User Meta](http://meta.superuser.com) why your question there might be off-topic. There's no point in trying to get it resurrected here; it's *definitely* off-topic here.